# Tunneled TLS WI-FI connection on Ubuntu 15.04 does not work

Tags: wireless, 15.04, wpa2, tls

I am trying to connect to a Wi-Fi connection on Ubuntu 15.04.
The connection uses WPA & WPA2 Enterprise, Tunneled TLS authentication, MSCHAPv2 as Inner authentication.

I was able to connect with Ubuntu 14, but not with Ubuntu 15.04.

The output from

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

is:

> 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
>
> Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2208]
>
> Kernel driver in use: ath9k

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved by changing the Authentication into Protected EAP (PEAP). (On Ubuntu 14.04 I used this connection by Tunneled TLS)